# Screen resolution detector putting browser in endless refresh state - WHY?

Tags: javascript

I've been working on a landing page for my company (http://apptest.wgsdac.org/ctc_parts).  I'm using a javascript code to detect the my users' screen resolution and automatically redirect accordingly.  Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (screen.width>1279){
 window.location="index.html";
}
else
{
 window.location="index_1024.html";
}
</script>
```

The problem is that when the page loads and the first condition is evaluated and satisfied the code works fine.  So I change my screen's resolution in order to trigger the second condition - upon refreshing the page the browser goes into a continuous refreshing loop.

Is there something wrong with the code, or am I doing it wrong?  Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious why you would need two different pages for different resolutions, could you account for those differences in your CSS?

Comment: can't you make a layout that is compatible with both large and small screens? or detect resizes using JS to put stuff appropriately on screen just like how smashingmagazine.com does it's layout?

Comment: Guys, thanks for your comments.  I'm not that experienced with CSS that's why I decided to take this approach.  But I'm still learning, so perhaps I might figure out how to do this via CSS.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it loading the same page with that code on it and keeps saying, yep I am in that range and loads it.

Why have two separate pages? Use [css3 media queries](http://www.css3.info/preview/media-queries/) to have different styles based on different widths

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I read up on the side you suggested, and studied up on media queries.  I had to modify my content a little, but managed to get it to work.  Thanks again.